# WPF ProgressBar Loaded event only triggering once

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using MVVM and have my MainWindow with the following property binding:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MainContentControl" Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" Margin="10,50,10,38"/>
```

On a button click, I am setting CurrentPage to the new view binding, which has a ProgressCarControl on it:

```
private void HomeButtonClick(object obj)
        {
            CurrentPage = new HomeViewModel();
        }


<ProgressBar Cursor="Hand"
            Name="EffortProgressBar" Value="{Binding Home.Effort, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, 
            Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource ProgressForegroundConverter}}" 
            Height="12" Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="75" Width="25" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </ProgressBar.RenderTransform>
            <ProgressBar.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ProgressBar.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" From="0" To="{Binding Home.Effort, Mode=TwoWay}" Duration="0:0:01"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ProgressBar.Triggers>
        </ProgressBar>
```

When I click the homebutton to load the page, the ProgressBar animates correctly, but when I click the button again, the ProgressBar does not animate.

Is there a different event to subscribe to to achieve this? Or will this not be possible?

Comment: Since it is already loaded it is not getting animated. try replacing with any other events

Comment: Why don't you trigger the animation on the button click event instead? That is, after all, what you actually want, isn't it? Your question isn't very clear. It lacks a [mcve], as well as details that would help us understand what you've tried and what _specifically_ you are having trouble with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I cannot do it on the button click as I have no access to the control on the ViewModel.

Comment: What's the view model got to do with it? Just put the event trigger in the XAML. If you still need help, fix your question. Provide a good [mcve], and explain exactly what it is you need. See [ask], and especially the articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTemplate` doesn't get reloaded when you set the source property that the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` is bound to a new value of the same type.

The easiest workaround would probably be to clear the `Content` by setting the `CurrentPage` property to null just before you set it back to a new instance of the `HomeViewModel`. For this to work you need to return to the caller and let the dispatcher update the UI before you reset the `CurrentPage` property:

```
private async void HomeButtonClick(object obj)
{
    if (CurrentPage != null && CurrentPage is HomeViewModel)
    {
        CurrentPage = null;
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
    CurrentPage = new HomeViewModel();
}
```

This should force the view to be reloaded.